# Elementary question on measure.

Tags: measure-theory

I have a very elementary question about measure.

When a note explains about the monotonicity of measure,
"if $A\leq B$, then $\mu(A)\leq\mu(B)$",
it saids we should write this out in $\mu(B\setminus A)=\mu(B)-\mu(A)$
rather than in $\mu(B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B\setminus A)$ because of the case
$\mu(A)=\mu(B)=\infty$.
I am a bit confused about the BAD result of the first form in this case.
Would you please let me know the point of this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think you have said it the other way round. You should express the thing as $\mu(B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B\setminus A)$, and not as $\mu(B\setminus A)=\mu(B)-\mu(A)$, because $\infty-\infty$ is not defined, and hence if $\mu(A)=\mu(B)=\infty$, then the rhs of the second equation $\mu(B\setminus A)=\mu(B)-\mu(A)$ is undefined.

Comment: Oh.. I misread the contents of the note. Thank you for letting me know, Abishanka!